# PHP exec() on Heroku is not working

Tags: php, python, heroku

i have an app on heroku that calls a python script, on localhost this works fine, but when i push to heroku's server exec doesnt work. I'm using a simple code only for test.

PHP

```
$result = exec("python testscript.py");
```

Python

```
def get_test():
    return 2
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print get_test()
```

Edit:  im using Multiple Buildpacks, my app is configured to use php and python

Comment: Is python installed, is `exec` allowed?

Comment: If you do `exec("ls -al")` for example, do you get the correct result ?

Comment: On localhost my code works fine so I guess it's allowed

Comment: Yes if a execute this command i got some result, thing that was not happening when running the python script

Comment: I discover what's going on, on my localhost i use Python 2,7, on heroku he uses 3.0 hahaha thanks for help guys